# how to set screen orientation like landscape view programmaticaly in iphone

Tags: iphone

Im trying to developing a screen orientation in landscape view.

here in my application i completed in portrait view but i trying to view like a landscape view also.

can any one plz help me of my problem. screen orientation in landscape view programmaticaly in iphone

thankyou in advance

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
return YES
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
- (void) applicationDidFinishLaunching: (UIApplication*) application
{
    CGRect screenBounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];

   m_window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame: screenBounds];
  viewController = [[MYViewController alloc] init];
  [m_window addSubview:viewController.view];
  [m_window makeKeyAndVisible];
}


- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:  (UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
  // Return YES for supported orientations
     return ((interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) );
}
```

in all the view controller

set key value in info.plist file

```
UIInterfaceOrientation UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight
```

Answer (score 1):

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {

    return YES;


}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
return YES
}
```

Make sure you have set the auto-resizing property for the view you want to display.