# iphone for Orientation

Tags: iphone, uiinterfaceorientation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to force a screen orientation in specific view controllers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/314382/how-to-force-a-screen-orientation-in-specific-view-controllers)

hello

I want to set the orientation in one particular view so how can i do that. andbody have example for that. i used the

```
-(void)onUIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification:(NSNotification*)notification{
    UIViewController *tvc = self.navigationController.topViewController;
    UIDeviceOrientation orientation = [[ UIDevice currentDevice ] orientation ];
    tabBarController.view.hidden = YES;
    // only switch if we need to (seem to get multiple notifications on device)
    if( orientation != [[ UIApplication sharedApplication ] statusBarOrientation ] ){
        if( [ tvc shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: orientation ] ){
            [ self rotateInterfaceToOrientation: orientation ];
        }
    }
}
```

but its done is whole application and i want to done only in one screen so please reply
thank you

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/314382/how-to-force-a-screen-orientation-in-specific-view-controllers, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3686303/uiviewcontroller-rotating-problem and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5297103/how-to-set-screen-orientation-like-landscape-view-programmaticaly-in-iphone

Comment: do u want to apply single orientation for your app???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on a particula view controller put

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}
```

this is for potrait for other u can do like wise

Answer (score 0):

```
// Override to allow orientations other than the default portrait orientation.
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    // Over ride this method in your required view controller to display only in the necessary orientation
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this method in your class

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    // Over ride this method in your required view controller to display only in the necessary orientation
     return YES;
}
```